# try and catch is not handling exception in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, nsexception

i am using the following code to catch an error when ind.row is not a valid value or sometimes it becomes nil

```
@try {
        if(ind.row<[[treeNode flattenElements] count])
        {
            [self.mTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ind atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
        }


    }
    @catch (NSException *e) {
        NSLog(@"%@",e);

    }
```

but when this code executes sometimes this error is occuring

```
Assertion failure in -[NSIndexPath row], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1262.60.3/UITableViewSupport.m:1948`
```

what may be the reason for this error and why exception is not being handled

Comment: I don't know about iphone, but, I think you should also add `@catch (Exception *ee) {` `NSLog(@"%@",ee);}`

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to catch an assertion failure to begin with. Your `NSIndexPath` was created incorrectly.

Comment: @KevinBallard actually what i am doing is in textfielddidbeginediting i pass the index of that cell to a ivar called ind by   ind=[[self.mTableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell*)textField.superview] retain];     then in the keyboardwasshown method,i use the above code for the textfield to scroll up when keyboard appears,but this is giving errors like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually it was already catching the exceptions...i had set the flag stop on objc exceptions.when i removed that it catching the exceptions.... as pointed out by @stilesCrisis the ind value was null at the time of this exception..sorry for the trble

Answer (score 3):

Assertions in iOS don't throw exceptions, so you can't catch them.

You are going to need to figure out what's wrong with your call to `-row`. My first guess would be that "ind" is already freed or something.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to check the index, generate and raise an exception on you own:[NSException Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSException_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
+ (void)raise:(NSString *)name format:(NSString *)format, ...
```